# Matplotlib force equal size with and without axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am fairly certain that this question has been asked and answered on Stackoverflow before, but I could not find the correct search term for it.

My situation is the following: I am producing individual figures in Matplotlib, and afterwards arrange multiple plots in a LaTeX figure (for the sake of the example, assume a `2x2` grid of subfigures in LaTeX, with indexing

```
a)   b)
c)   d)
```

For "visual niceness", I want to only describe the y-axis ticks in a) and c), and x-axis ticks only in plots c) and d). While disabling the axis ticks on the respective subfigures is quite easy, it unfortunately causes the saved figures to come out with different image sizes (the plot region takes up more of the image if no axis labels are present), which subsequently messes up the layout in my LaTeX figure.

Is there any way to force the specific size of these plots, based on the size of plot c) (having both axis ticks)?

My current attempt has been to use `plt.savefig([...], bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=x)`, but to no avail.
I am also open to using `plt.subplot()`, but I would prefer to keep them as individual plots for the sake later presentations.

For reference and to give you some MCVE to work with, imagine the plot of subfigure a) (no x-axis label and ticks) to look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4], [])  # Disable x-axis ticks
plt.xlabel("")  # Disable x-axis label
```

Comment: Remove `bbox_inches='tight',`. Then the figure size will always be the same.

Comment: Is there some reason to not use `subplots` and plot the four panels on one figure?  Then you can uses `sharex` and `sharey` to get the effect you want and all the subplots will be the same size, unless you start changing aspect ratios.

Comment: In latex, one can use subfigures to give caption and reference to individual figures(subplots), which make it look more standard there.
I'm also facing the same issue because of this